# How to show static image when a site hosting Flash is blocked

Tags: flash

I'm trying to load a youtube video in a webpage. Not overly difficult, and works fine.

```
<object width="600" height="362"> 
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/etc"></param> 
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param> 
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/etc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
width="600" height="362" 
allowfullscreen="true">
</embed> 
</object>
```

There is no problem if Flash is not present or disabled - it just shows whats in the middle of the embed.

But if youtube is blocked (at the firewall, or /etc/hosts pointing to the wrong IP), I just get nothing.

Anyone know of a way to display something in this case? eg an image (or any html for that matter).

[edit] I guess I should add: I dont have access to Flash, so I can't make a new SWF and embed it (sorry, George, the idea looks good, but I dont have the tools).

I need something which I can do in HTML and Javascript, on the client. Ta.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to load the video and listen for an HTTPStatus event, a security error, anything that might let you know the video won't work, if so display alternate content ?

```
var ytLoader:Loader = new Loader();
ytLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, ytHTTPStatus);
ytLoader.load(new URLRequest('http://www.youtube.com/v/kDKiQfBs9lo'));

function ytHTTPStatus(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
    if(event.status != 200) trace('display alternate content');
}
```

If you can only access stuff through Javascript, I suggest having a look at the [YouTubePlayer API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

I'm guessing that if there is any problem with displaying a video, that should be visible if you try to access any data from the video like:

- [video information](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Retrieving_video_information)( duration,
  video url, video embed code )
- not much change going on through the
  [onStateChange event](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#SubscribingEvents).

HTH

Comment: In the end, not so much. I dont have access to any ActionScript - only  javascript/html. The swfobject has a callback, but it says ok even if I point youtube.com to 127.0.0.1.....

Comment: can you access any data through the JS API ? links provided above